# manage.py celeryd -l INFO

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, djcelery

When i run

```
./manage.py celeryd -l INFO
```

I am getting the following error

> Running a worker with superuser privileges when the worker accepts
>   messages serialized with pickle is a very bad idea!
>       If you really want to continue then you have to set the C_FORCE_ROOT environment variable (but please think about this before
>   you do).
>
> User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0

Stuck with this issue is there any one who can solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is clear. Don't run this as root.

In fact, don't run anything as root. You shouldn't be logged in as root at all.